# Networking in VMware

Tags: sql-server, vmware

I am required to imitate a remote database server environment for my project. So I am thinking of installing SQL Server 2008 on a virtual machine (VMware workstation) and then access it from my computer.

How do I find the address of the SQL server instance in the virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this:
After installing the `SQL Server` on the `VMware` try to connect to the SQL server by using `SQL MAnagement Studio`, see what the server name and use it to connect from your default OS you have on your machine

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you installed it, you'll have to configure it and open up the firewall.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx

If you hit all the defaults in SQL Server Setup, then you just need to open up a firewall port.  Inside the VM, you can type this into the CMD prompt:

`netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1433 "SQLPort"`

TCP  1433 is the default port.  The default SQL server instance I think is called MSSQL.

If you also want to allow the Browser Service (So you can browse the available SQL instances rather than trying to access them by CLI), then you'll need to open port UDP 1434.
`netsh firewall set portopening UDP 1434 "SQL Browser"

**Or you can just go EZ mode and open everything SQL Server uses:**

```
@echo =========  SQL Server Ports  =================== 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1433 "SQLServer" 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 1434 "SQL Admin Connection" 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 4022 "SQL Service Broker" 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 135 "SQL Debugger/RPC" 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2383 "Analysis Services" 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 2382 "SQL Browser" 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 80 "HTTP" 
netsh firewall set portopening TCP 443 "SSL" 
netsh firewall set portopening UDP 1434 "SQL Browser" 
netsh firewall set multicastbroadcastresponse ENABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

If by address you mean IP address, it will be the same than the virtual machine itself. Just run an `ipconfig` command to get it.